# Loading data into Mysql table from file over SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh

Server1 has a MySQL server, Server2 has a file which I need to import into a table Server1's MySQL server. I can only access Server2 and it's files using SSH.

Now what can be the best solution for this? One inefficient method would be to `scp` the file onto Server2's hard disk, then execute a  `LOAD DATA INFILE` for that file. But since the file is large, I want to avoid doing this.

Is there a way to directly load the file into Server1's Mysql from Server2?

Answer (score 3):

```
cat file.sql | ssh -C -c blowfish username@myserver mysql -u username -p database_name
```

In this command, -C enables compression during transfer and -c blowfish selects a cyphering algorithm that uses less CPU than the default one.

Common sense would suggest to transfer the compressed file so that you can verify the checksum with for example MD5 and then run the import from the compressed file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ssh tunneling to access your mysql server remotely and securely.

The following command will create the port forwarding:

```
$ ssh -f -L <[local address:]port>:<remote address;port> -N <user id>
```

For example:

```
$ ssh -F -L 45678:localhost:3307 -N foo@localhost
```

will forward the default mysql server port on localhost to the port `45678`  using foo's credentials (this may be useful for testing purposes).

Then, you may simply connect to the server with your local program:

```
$ mysql -p -u foo -P 45678
```

At the mysql prompt, it is possible to bulk load a data file using the `LOAD DATA` statement, which takes the optional keyword `LOCAL` to indicate that the file is located on the client end of the connection.

Documentation:

- [ssh manual page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/ssh.1.php)
- [`LOAD DATA` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/load-data.html)